# build a varchar using the first four characters of a uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have an ID such as:

```
61759092-5066-4D02-A0E4-000084E9E68D
```

The result I would like is:

```
\6\1\7\5
```

This is my way:

```
  select '\' + substring(CAST(idField as varchar(38)),1,1) 
  + '\' + substring(CAST(idField as varchar(38)),2,1) 
  + '\' + substring(CAST(idField as varchar(38)),3,1) 
  + '\' + substring(CAST(idField as varchar(38)),4,1) 
  from mytable
```

It works, but something is telling me, I'm using way too much overhead to do this.

is there a smarter, more efficient way to do this?

**How do i get the first four characters of a uniqueidentifier separated by '\'?**

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: Dynamics CRM uses the first four characters of a GUID to identify the location of a file

Comment: If it's a relatively low insert/update volume, you could make a calculated field that stores the value you are looking for. Anytime a new record is inserted or updated, there is a small bit of overhead, but it would make it very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is any better but here is what I came up with.

```
Select
    left(x.id, 1) + '\' +
    left(right(x.Id, 3), 1) + '\' +
    left(right(x.Id, 2), 1) + '\' +
    right(x.Id, 1)
From
    (
        Select Left(cast(idField as varchar(38)), 4)  as Id
        From myTable
    ) x
```

Comment: I too liked this one. I am afraid but will give +1.

Answer (score 1):

Example of my suggestion in the comments above

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (
    [uid] uniqueidentifier,
    CRM AS (    
            '\' + substring(CAST([uid] as varchar(38)),1,1) 
              + '\' + substring(CAST([uid] as varchar(38)),2,1) 
              + '\' + substring(CAST([uid] as varchar(38)),3,1) 
              + '\' + substring(CAST([uid] as varchar(38)),4,1) 
            )
)

INSERT INTO @tmp([uid])
    SELECT NEWID()

SELECT * FROM @tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the stuff function to accomplish this.

```
Select stuff(Stuff(Stuff(Stuff(Left(Cast(idField As VarChar(38)), 4),1,0,'\'), 3,0,'\'), 5,0,'\'), 7,0,'\')
from myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

May not be an efficient one but give it a try though

```
select REPLACE((SPACE(1)+
SUBSTRING('61759092-5066-4D02-A0E4-000084E9E68D',1,1)+SPACE(1)
+SUBSTRING('61759092-5066-4D02-A0E4-000084E9E68D',2,1)+SPACE(1)
+SUBSTRING('61759092-5066-4D02-A0E4-000084E9E68D',3,1)+SPACE(1)
+ SUBSTRING('61759092-5066-4D02-A0E4-000084E9E68D',4,1)+SPACE(1)
),' ','/')
```

Comment: why adding space and then replace with '/' ?

Comment: @dllhell, just another way of doing; though I can directly concat with `/`.

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
SELECT     COALESCE('\'+SUBSTRING(idField ,1,1) ,'')  +
           COALESCE('\'+SUBSTRING(idField ,1+1,1) ,'')  +
           COALESCE('\'+SUBSTRING(idField ,1+2,1) ,'')  +
           COALESCE('\'+SUBSTRING(idField ,1+3,1) ,'') as id
FROM mytable
```

Comment: @G Mastros, did not know about the stuff function. Thanks.